# What database permissions do you give a Rails app?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, rails-activestorage

What mysql/postgres permissions do you give to the Rails database user? Full access?

I'm just paranoid and would rather the Rails app not perform certain functions such as truncating or dropping a table?

Comment: Sufficient permissions in order for the Rails database user to fulfill their assigned tasks.

Comment: The rails app absolutely needs to be able to create, drop, reset, and migrate the database, checkout the rails db tasks, therefore the rails database user needs full permissions.